# Add Tapit to an APK made with GameSalad using smali?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, smali, gamesalad

Just to clear up my question a little more, what I need to do, is implement Tapit SDK to an android APK made by GameSalad.

I know mostly the entire process already, and my only problem is getting the ad to show.

To give you a quick run through of my method, I decompile the apk to smali with apktool, I also have a tapit apk that I decompile so I can just have the smali code for that, and then I put it inside the activity I need it in. I make sure I import tapit, add the lib folder under com, edit the android manifest xml, and then recompile, and resign.

The app doesn't crash anymore, but it doesn't show my ad either.

I know it is possible to edit an apk in this manner, and I also know about dex2jar and editing it in jasmine, but I can't get it to work that way either.

If anyone would have any insight on this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to add adds so you earn money into an application somone else developed by reverse engineering it?

Comment: No, not at all lol. My company made this app, and GameSalad only supports ads on iOS currently, and it is a free app. So they want me to put ads in the android version with tapit, since GameSalad does not support ads on Android yet.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My bad, thought GameSalad was an app or something. Not a tool to create  apps.

Comment: All good! I understand your concern. :)

Comment: This seems generally workable; the catch would be you'll need to call into it to start it up.  What you could do is build a very simple case of that into a dummy Activity (or Service?) in a conventional android app, and then cut & paste that smali code over to the activity you want to add ads to.  You might also be able to trigger it by using a custom class in a layout.

Answer (score 0):

just add the jar file from the ad provider SDK to the decompiled apk and you are done:)

Comment: That won't work by itself.  You have to call into it at some point, otherwise the dead code will just sit there.  Also, you probably can't use the jar file - more likely, to get things in the same format you'd merge the output of decompiling a conventional dummy app containing the ad code, and that of decompiling the framework generated real app.